# Combination of elements in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

I'm trying to write a SPARQL query on top of an ontology, starting from a previous one that gives me this kind of results:

[image: Results from the previous query]

Obtained with the following query:

```
PREFIX  vg:   <http://example.org/vg/>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?path (GROUP_CONCAT(?sequence ; separator='') AS ?pathSeq)
WHERE
  { ?step  vg:path    ?path ;
           vg:node    ?node ;
           vg:rank    ?rank .
    ?node  rdf:value  ?sequence
  }
GROUP BY ?path
ORDER BY ASC(MAX(?rank))
```

As you can see, i have a table of key:value items (let me describe them in a simple way), where the key is **path** and the value is **pathSeq**.

So, starting from

- `path_A | pathSeq_A`;
- `path_B | pathSeq_B`;
- `path_C | pathSeq_C`;
- ...

What i need to do is write a SPARQL query in order to have, for each **path**, all the possible *distinct* combinations:

- `[path_A | pathSeq_A - path_B | pathSeq_B]`;
- `[path_A | pathSeq_A - path_C | pathSeq_C]`;
- `[path_B | pathSeq_B - path_C | pathSeq_C]`;
- ...

Here you can [see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CIHg.png) of the desired output

[image: see an example]

**NOTES:** The RDF has been built with VG (you can find some description [here](https://github.com/vgteam/vg/wiki/RDF%3A-for-VG)). The RDF on which i'm working on is available at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A2vWwBq-SHxAXTF9T3ZOeY43Lo_9lnmW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide some sample data (valid RDF, ideally N-Triples syntax)

Comment: The RDF has been built with VG (you can find some description [here](https://github.com/vgteam/vg/wiki/RDF%3A-for-VG)). The RDF on which i'm working on is available at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A2vWwBq-SHxAXTF9T3ZOeY43Lo_9lnmW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LFwB1S53 ?

Comment: Your desired output jpg shows something other than what you've said you want. `pathA seqA pathB seqB` is not "for each path"...

Comment: @StanislavKralin Yes, it was very useful, thanks!

Comment: @TallTed It was a toy example, limiting the results